# In Google Compute Engine, how is total processing power effected by vCPUs to core ratio and visible core count?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When creating a virtual machine instance, for example n1-standard-4 which has 4 vCPUs, I am allowed to select "vCPUs to core ratio" and "Visible core count".

**vCPUs to core ratio:**

> [Google](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/set-threads-per-core?_ga=2.237319488.-1116392726.1677477272): "When the number of threads per core is set to 1, the CPU utilization metric can only scale up to a maximum of 50%. When the number of threads per core is set to 2, the CPU utilization metric can scale up to 100%."

If I select "1 vCPU per core", does that mean that I am getting 1 vCPU with theoretically 2X the processing power of 1 vCPU had I selected "2 vCPUs per core"? Or am I leaving half of my processing power unused?

**Visible core count:**

> [Google](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/customize-visible-cores?_ga=2.141573618.-1116392726.1677477272): "When the number of visible cores is reduced, the CPU utilization metric can not scale up to 100%. It is limited to the number of visible CPU cores divided by the maximum number of CPU cores."

If I select "1 core 1 vCPU", does that mean that I am getting 1 vCPU that uses an entire physical core? Additionally, am I removing processing power from the VM and paying for unused cores?